# magento 2.4.6 checkout not working

Tags: magento2, orders

we have been getting following error in checkout page.  error are coming after migration we are using lit-extension for data migration.

1. In the console on checkout page I see following error

Error : "message": ""%fieldName" is required. Enter and try again.",
"parameters": {
"fieldName": "email"
},

```
error screen-shot : https://app.screencast.com/OuOsFuiwd360d
```

2. In the console on checkout page i see following error

Error :   POST /rest/default/V1/guest-carts/CLp5qSkaU2BIvfryOwRwC6NyanapbN6w/set-payment-information 400 (Bad Request)

screen-shot : https://app.screencast.com/ZsDrc1rn69YAx

```
 Above two error comes when you login as customer and add 1 or 2 bookings in the cart and when you go in checkout you get logged on checkout page or when you try to click on place order button order doesn't go through give error.
```

we are using stripe payment method.

```
  Please let us know what causing this issue.
```

i have tried bellow reference  code but not worked

9

/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information Is the rest api which map to PaymentInformationManagementInterface. Here mine means you are logged in customer.

Open vendor/magento/module-checkout/etc/webapi.xml here actually map.

When you click Place Order button, magento call vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php

savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder

```
public function savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
) {
    $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
    try {
        $orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __($e->getMessage()),
            $e
        );
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->getLogger()->critical($e);
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.'),
            $e
        );
    }
    return $orderId;
}
```

-> we do not have term and condition enable in our site.

-> i have also migrate sequence table of order , invoice and credit memo

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause of this issue is that some third-party extension is conflicting with the checkout functionality. **You can try disabling or removing the extension and running the following commands to clear the cache and deploy the static content.**

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush